# How to construct descriptors for irregularly shaped image patches

Tags: image-processing, object-recognition

As hinted in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6008/1273), **Perceptual hashing** is a way to ascribe comparable measures (hashes) to images (rectangular patches). The images do not need to be the same size, and can be slightly distorted, according to the answer.

I might soon need a way to measurably describe image patches of *different sizes*, as well as *irregular* (not only different) *shapes*, and if Perceptual hashing could be adapted to work on non-rectangular image patches, it sounds interesting in this context.

I don't have any limitation to the way I describe the patches though, so any other suggestions are welcome. *It does not have to be a distance measure*, in other words, I just want a measure with a *tendency* to:

- be more similar between patches of similar shape
- be more similar between patches of similar content (similar subparts of the image)
- still tolerate slight distortion in shapes and pixel values
- can be but does not have to be more similar for shapes of similar size

Comment: Can you give an example image? Without the binarisation, perceptual hashes would be vectors of DCT coefficients, and comparison would be a distance measure.

Comment: @geometrikal I opened this question as a response to the comments in [the linked answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6008/1273). The answer got me thinking ahead to something I might need in a few months, and what I wanted to ask was out of the scope of that question. So, I opened a new one. But, I won't have example images in a while, sorry :(

Comment: @penelope Quick note: I liked your answers on the previous question, they were quite good! Anyway...for your irregular patches, would you be able to fit a contour (of arbitrary degree) to your irregular patches, hash the contour, and then construct a texture hash using, for example, a shape-adaptive DCT approach? Smash them together into one hash afterwards?

Comment: @Eric Nope, not really for contours. They would probably be patches (or merged patches) determined by some (fine) segmenting technique. So, on a fine level, (median) color, area, and maybe elongation are okay, but when I merge them using various criteria, they become less homogeneous so I would need something more complex.