# How does Image Search on Google + work

Tags: image-processing

I found out today about Google +'s [image search feature](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/05/21/googles-best-new-unadvertised-feature-photo-search-with-visual-recognition-try-it-on-your-own-pictures-and-be-amazed/). It allows users to perform a text-based search for objects within their picture library. I was instantly curious to know how this feature works. Does anyone know? Are Google using anonymous usage patterns from Google Images to build a computer vision library of CBIR object descriptors?

Possibly related is Google's 'Search by image' feature - see [What algorithm does Google use for its "Search By Image" site?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/5995/what-algorithm-does-google-use-for-its-search-by-image-site).

Comment: Probably bag-of-words like model with text tags from their webcrawling, i.e. someone links to a picture of a snake with a link called 'snake'. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/104362980539466846301/posts/FXtd4otWxNX